# Full-text Indexing got stuck with error code 3602 and search was not working

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, full-text-catalog

Full-text index got stuck and search was not working. Please help me with this issue. It was fixed with a restart of the SQL Server, but i need to know the root cause of this issue. Kindly add your thoughts on it. If you need any more information please comment below. Below is the error which i got from logs.

> *An internal query to load data for a crawl on database 'DatabaseName' and table 'TableName' failed with error code 3602. Check the sql
>   error code for more information about the condition causing this
>   failure. The crawl needs to be restarted after this condition is
>   removed.*

Comment: Maybe service broker queue related. Better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @scsimon did as you said i got negative points for posting the same question.

Comment: They downvoted you because they didn't think your question was well done. Not because it was posted here.

Comment: More Info: Issue happened lately on SQL Server Standard Edition 2014.